# Code 404 when fetching image in Django template

Tags: html, django, image, django-templates

I am trying to fetch some images located in a folder. The path is correct but they appear as broken link with code 404.
MY files and configurations are as follows:
settings.py

```
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join( PROJECT_DIR, 'media/images/uploads')

# URL that handles the media served from MEDIA_ROOT. Make sure to use a
# trailing slash.
# Examples: "http://example.com/media/", "http://media.example.com/"
MEDIA_URL = '/media/images/uploads/'

# Absolute path to the directory static files should be collected to.
# Don't put anything in this directory yourself; store your static files
# in apps' "static/" subdirectories and in STATICFILES_DIRS.
# Example: "/var/www/example.com/static/"
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join( PROJECT_DIR, 'static')

# URL prefix for static files.
# Example: "http://example.com/static/", "http://static.example.com/"
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

# Additional locations of static files
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    'C:\Users\omars_000\Desktop\mytask\mytask\media\images',
    'C:\Users\omars_000\Desktop\mytask\mytask\media\images\uploads',
    'C:\Users\omars_000\Desktop\mytask\mytask\media',
)
```

models.py

```
class Pics(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
    docfile = models.ImageField(upload_to=content_file_name, null=True, blank=True)
    def __unicode__(self):  # Python 3: def __str__(self):
        return self.docfile
```

home.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"  "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
{% load staticfiles %}
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
        <title>Home Page</title>
        <link href="{{ STATIC_URL }}styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    </head>

    <body>
        <div id="background">
        Value of a is {{ imgs.0 }}

            <div id="background"><img src="{% static "images\background.png" %}""></div>
            <div id="Shape17copy"><img src="{% static "images\Shape17copy.png" %}""></div>
            <div id="About"><img src="{% static "images\About.png" %}""></div>
            <div id="Layer7">
            <img src="{% static "images\Layer7.png" %}"">
            {% if imgs %}
                {% for i in imgs %}
                <img src="{{i.docfile.url}}"/>                
                {% endfor %}
            {% else %}
            {% endif %}
            </div>
            <div id="Layer7copy"><img src="{% static "images\Layer7copy.png" %}""></div>
            <div id="Shape17copy2"><img src="{% static "images\Shape17copy.png" %}""></div>
            <div id="RecentWork"><img src="{% static "images\RecentWork.png" %}""></div>

        </div>
 </body>
 </html>
```

What could be my issue?!

Answer (score 1):

I have also faced this problem but it worked when I used hard coded URLs like this

```
    <img src="/static/images/background.png" />
```

And moreover use forward slash

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried forward slashes for the image paths in the `{% static %}` tags?

Update: check the syntax of your static tags: use single quotes for the filename inside the tag and fix the incorrect extra double quote at the end of each `img` tag

Comment: "GET" /media/images/uploads/img.jpg HTTP 1.1 404
That is what i see in the cmd

Comment: What does your webserver (apache, nginx, ect.) logs say?